# Entering Name With Accents on arXiv

Tags: arxiv, personal-name, latex

I'm trying to submit a paper on arXiv, but I can't figure out how to enter my name with accents.
It's supposed to say "Dörr", but arXiv turns it into this:
[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tHuzq.png)

I tried to enter the UTF character directly and also tried to use the latex syntax for accented characters, as described [here](https://arxiv.org/edit-user/tex-accents.php).
Using a different browser didn't help either.

On the same site it says "make sure [...] that any accented characters are properly represented", so it has to be possible to enter them.

Any ideas? It can't be that difficult.

Comment: Maybe that's just the site you're viewing that is misrepresenting it, while arXiv internally knows the right name? I wouldn't worry much about this; looks like a bug that will eventually be fixed even without your input.

Comment: Does the accent show up properly when you compile the LaTeX to pdf locally? Perhaps ask this at tex,stackexchange,com, with a minimal (non)working example.

Comment: @EthanBolker The question seems to be referring to the name in the arXiv web portal, not the paper itself.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I contacted the arXiv support, here's their reply:

"*This is actually something we manually fix later in the process, after you submit. Our legacy perl based system does not handle utf gracefully. If you proceed with the submission as is or with Tom D\"orr we will change it to Tom D\"orr in the metadata so that it will be displayed correctly.*

*We are also in the process of updating our code base to python/flask that will support utf.*"

Comment: Weird but okay. This should be accepted answer.

Comment: Weird? Buggy, actually. I understand they may need to manually fix some instances, but if their _normal_ process is to have that broken and manually change it, their code is at fault, sorry.

Comment: @Ángel That's exactly what arXiv support said.

Answer (score 4):

Your image shows that it is being represented as if it was double-encoded in utf-8. I would first ensure your browser isn't misconfigured to show arXiv page as latin-1 despite being utf-8. Then, given that providing the utf-8 characters fail to render properly, I would configure the page as being in windows-1252 (which would show lots of those artifacts) and try sending the name in that encoding (your browser will use the encoding in which the page was served) which, hopefully, might end up correctly encoded (it would still be a serious bug, though)

Howover, since you claim that you tried to input it as `D\"orr` and it still showed as `DÃ¶rr`, that leads me to think that it may be a local representation problem on your end (maybe some other part of the page produces a stray latin-1 character, which makes the browser conclude the page cannot be in utf-8?).

Note you can always [contact arXiv](https://arxiv.org/help/contact) about the error you are receiving.

Comment: If you want to check your browser configuration, here is a page where it works for me: https://arxiv.org/search/math?searchtype=author&query=D%C3%B6rr%2C+P

Comment: Can you explain or link to how to do these things? I think most people would have no idea how to do that.

Answer (score -4):

I got rid of accent marks. You'll always have problems with them.